How to enable HEIC file support in darktable in Jammy 22.04.4?
I'm trying to open a HEIC file to convert to jpg or png using darktable.   I'm using Kubuntu: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I have the latest version of darktable installable using apt from ubuntu packages, 4.6.1.  The version info for darktable is here:
$ darktable --version
this is darktable 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2012-2024 Johannes Hanika and other contributors.

Compile options:
  Bit depth              -> 64 bit
  Debug                  -> DISABLED
  SSE2 optimizations     -> ENABLED
  OpenMP                 -> ENABLED
  OpenCL                 -> ENABLED
  Lua                    -> ENABLED  - API version 9.2.0
  Colord                 -> ENABLED
  gPhoto2                -> ENABLED
  GMIC                   -> ENABLED  - Compressed LUTs are supported
  GraphicsMagick         -> ENABLED
  ImageMagick            -> DISABLED
  libavif                -> DISABLED
  libheif                -> DISABLED
  libjxl                 -> DISABLED
  OpenJPEG               -> ENABLED
  OpenEXR                -> ENABLED
  WebP                   -> ENABLED

Assuming libheif is what supports HEIC files, I tried installing libheif, but it doesn't exist, and I already have libheif1:
$ sudo apt install libheif
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libheif

$ sudo apt install libheif1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libheif1 is already the newest version (1.12.0-2build1).
libheif1 set to manually installed.

libheif seems to exist for jammy:  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libheif/1.12.0-2build1/+build/22381572
I have tried googling, but I can't see any info on how to enable HEIC/HEIF file support in darktable.  No-one else seems to have this issue.  How can I do it?  Preferably without compiling it myself. Thanks.

The version of darktable on Jammy is 3.8.1 (according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=darktable), and on Noble (24.04) it is 4.6.1. How did you get darktable 4.6.1 in Jammy? Are you using snap package? I installed darktable using APT in my 24.04 machine and it has libheif enabled.

Also, the latest version of darktable is 4.8.1

Thanks for that info about the latest version on Jammy.   It looks like I installed it by downloading the deb via https://www.darktable.org/install/ .  I see that there's a more recent version now:  darktable_4.8.1-1.1+80.1_amd64.deb  for 22.02.  However installing that has the same problem:  In the compile options libheif is disabled.  I have converted the file using convert IMG.heif IMG.png for now. (yes, Imagemagick supports it).

Can you try the (older) version from the official repositories? I don't have any problem with the version in the official repo (but I am using 24.04). Try sudo apt remove darktable && sudo apt update && sudo apt install darktable

@ArchismanPanigrahi that works, thanks.  However that takes me back to version 3.8.1 of darktable.  To get the downgrade working I had to delete the contents of the ~/.config/darktable/ directory.

The solution is to remove the darktable version downloaded from its website, and install it from the official repositories.
sudo apt remove darktable && sudo apt update && sudo apt install darktable

You may have to delete the config in ~/.config/darktable/ for the old version to work.

Can you add details about deleted the config too?

@kristianp Done

@kristianp If my answer worked for you, then you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left side
